# Rails - how to load the whole directory of files in /lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have in the lib directory following structure:

```
/lib/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c/
```

In `dir_c` are stored images.

I am trying to load these images and display them in views. I have tried to set up the path to the images in views, but I got the 404 error.

So I did following: created a file in the `initializers` folder and into this file I put:

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/dir_a'].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

For loading all content stored in the **dir_a** directory (which involves as subdirectories as files).
But when I restarted server, I got this error:

```
...dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/radek/rubydev/EDI/lib/brands (LoadError)
```

I also tried stuff like

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/dir_a/'].each do |file|
```

or

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/dir_a/**'].each do |file|
```

But none of those helped me.

Thus, is there any way to load a content from **/lib** directory and work with them in views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/**/*.rb'].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this partially helped me. The problem but is, that when I try to load this image in browser, like **localhost:3001/lib/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c/image.png**, I get error **No route matches [GET] /lib/...**. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Loading those libraries and routing to those images are two separate things. The route needs to be defined elsewhere, e.g. `config/routes.rb`.